# How to write a like query in HQL

Tags: java, hibernate, hql, sql-like

I want to perform search for a particular string that is starting with a particular alphabet.

So, for example if the starting alphabet is `'A'` then it should produce a result which will contain all the strings with alphabet `'A'`.

How do I achieve this ?

My query is as shown below:

```
Query qry = session.createQuery("From RegistrationBean as rb where rb."+searchCriteria+"  like %?%");
qry.setString(0,searchField);
```

Comment: And `like` is not working for you?

Comment: no there is some problem with my query i think.




Query qry = session.createQuery("From RegistrationBean as rb where rb."+searchCriteria+" like %?%")
qry.setString(0,searchField);

Comment: [What have you tried?](https://whathaveyoutried.com) Please post what you have so far in the question.

Comment: Do we have to guess? Show you query?

Answer (score 31):

Change your query to this:

```
Query qry = session.createQuery("From RegistrationBean as rb where rb."+searchCriteria+"  like ?");
qry.setString(0, "%"+searchField+"%");
```

Comment: is this not vulnerable to SQL injection?

Comment: @OptimusPrime No, it is.

Answer (score 18):

You can use criteria for using like

```
session = sessionFactory.openSession();
Criteria query = session.createCriteria(Pojo.class);
query.add(Restrictions.like("column", "a", MatchMode.START));
```

It will give you the list of string which start by alpha-bate 'a'.

Answer (score 12):

Change to

```
Query qry = session.createQuery("From RegistrationBean as rb where rb ";
if (searchField != null)
{
    qry = qry + " where rb.searchCriteria like :searchField ";
}
if ( searchField!= null)
{
    query.setString("searchField","%"+searchField+"%");
}
```

Comment: I would do that with two separate queries.

Answer (score 10):

This way

```
createQuery("from RegistrationBean as rb where rb.:searchCriteria like '%:searchField%'");
```

Comment: Have you heard anything about SQL injection? http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection One have to use parameter binding to avoid it.

Comment: This link have nothing with hibernate and hql.

Comment: https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Preventing_SQL_Injection_in_Java

Comment: Well, there's nothing vulnerable found, to make more sense the query above does not contain user input.

Comment: How do you know that? The `searchField` parameter could be entered by user.

Comment: if searchField = "' OR '1'='1" then it is subject to sql injection

Comment: @Oleksii However this is to old post for downvote, I changed it because it's not about sql injection but it doesn't matter, everyone who answered with `"+searchCriteria+"` should be downvoted?

Comment: @RomanC there are three types of responses: upvote, downvote, ignore. Welcome.