# java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Integer cannot be cast to java.math.BigInteger HTTP Status 500

Tags: java, mysql, sql, hibernate

I'm getting the following exception.

> HTTP Status 500 - Request processing failed; nested exception is
>   java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Integer cannot be cast to
>   java.math.BigInteger

with the following code

Emploee.Contoller.java

```
@RequestMapping("searchEmployee")
    public ModelAndView searchEmployee(@RequestParam("searchName") String searchName) {  
        logger.info("Searching the Employee. Employee Names: "+searchName);
        List<Employee> employeeList = employeeService.getAllEmployees(searchName);
        return new ModelAndView("employeeList", "employeeList", employeeList);      
    }
```

EmployeeDAOImpl.java

```
@Override
    public List<Employee> getAllEmployees(String employeeName) { 
        String query = "SELECT e.* FROM Employees e WHERE e.name like '%"+ employeeName +"%'";
        List<Object[]> employeeObjects = hibernateUtil.fetchAll(query);
        List<Employee> employees = new ArrayList<Employee>();
        for(Object[] employeeObject: employeeObjects) {
            Employee employee = new Employee();
            long id = ((BigInteger) employeeObject[0]).longValue();
            String name = (String) employeeObject[1];
            int age = (int) employeeObject[2];
            int admin = (int) employeeObject[3];
            boolean isAdmin=false;
            if(admin==1)
            isAdmin=true;
            Date createdDate = (Date) employeeObject[4];
            employee.setId(id);
            employee.setName(name);
            employee.setAge(age);
            employee.setAdmin(isAdmin);
            employee.setCreatedDate(createdDate);
            employees.add(employee);
        }
        System.out.println(employees);
        return employees;
    }
```

at this line

```
long id = ((BigInteger) employeeObject[0]).longValue();
```

Does anybody have any idea?

Comment: BigInt and Long are not same. Try-> long id = ((Long) employeeObject[0]).longValue(); Check this page: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/lang/long_longvalue.htm

Comment: Can you try this.

`long id  = Long.parseLong(String.valueOf(employeeObject[0]))` ? this should work,

Comment: changed,interesting,now i got new exception is java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Boolean cannot be cast to java.lang.Integer

Comment: Deendayal Garg,long id = Long.parseLong(String.valueOf(employeeObject[0]))  it helped, you can duplicate the answer, so that I can choose it as a right.

Comment: Why aren't you using HQL ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are executing sql statement and creating objects manually. If you use HQL or criteria Hibernate does it for you, and simplifies things. 
Use parametrized query, is a good practice, helps in preventing SQL injection

```
@Override
        public List<Employee> getAllEmployees(String employeeName) { 
            String query = "SELECT e.* FROM Employees e WHERE e.name like '%"+ employeeName +"%'";
            List<Object[]> employeeObjects = hibernateUtil.fetchAll(query);
            List<Employee> employees = new ArrayList<Employee>();
            for(Object[] employeeObject: employeeObjects) {
                Employee employee = new Employee();
                long id = ((BigInteger) employeeObject[0]).longValue();
                String name = (String) employeeObject[1];
                int age = (int) employeeObject[2];
                int admin = (int) employeeObject[3];
                boolean isAdmin=false;
                if(admin==1)
                isAdmin=true;
                Date createdDate = (Date) employeeObject[4];
                employee.setId(id);
                employee.setName(name);
                employee.setAge(age);
                employee.setAdmin(isAdmin);
                employee.setCreatedDate(createdDate);
                employees.add(employee);
            }
            System.out.println(employees);
            return employees;
        }
```

When you use HQL it looks like this

```
    @Override
        public List<Employee> getAllEmployees(String employeeName) { 
        Session session = //initialize session            
        Query query = session.createQuery("FROM Employees e WHERE e.name like '%"+ ? + "%'");
           query.setParameter(0, "%"+employeeName+"%");
           List<Employee>  employees = query.list();
           System.out.println(employees);
           return employees;
        }
```

[Check This Ans](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13562261/how-to-write-a-like-query-in-hql)

Answer (score 0):

Your `id` is of type `long`, so try to cast it to `Long` instead of `BigInteger`.

Like this: `long id = (Long) employeeObject[0].longValue();`

Hope this helps !

Comment: long id = (Long) employeeObject[0].longValue(); incorrect line, and i am repeating that me helped this long id = Long.parseLong(String.valueOf(employeeObject[0]))