# HQL query with LIKE % is not wokring

Tags: java, sql, hibernate, jpa, hql

I tried to reproduce this SQL query which is working for me, havent copied exact syntax for privacy issues, but I think you get the purpose from this query.

```
SELECT t1.Column1, t2.Column2, t2.Column3
FROM Table1 as t1
INNER JOIN Table2 as t2 ON t1.Column1 LIKE %t2.Column2%
INNER JOIN Table2 as t2 ON t1.Column1 LIKE %t2.Column3% ;
```

while on the HQL query I tried this but it doesnt seem to get me any results :

> returns empty list [ ]

HQL query :

```
session.createQuery("... where
t1.Column1 LIKE '%"+"t2.Column2"+"%'
and t1.Column1 LIKE '%"+"t2.Column3"+"%' ").list();
```

I've tried to insert actual values instead of columns, it does actually work, but i think hibernate treats attributes as raw values instead of iterating over the objects.
Can anyone please suggest a solution , I've seen people approaching this issue with criterias, but the main problem is that I'm not making any associations between these classes so I don't think it'd work.

I've been stuck with this problem for over a week now, one very easy solution that comes to my mind but it's not really optimal, is doing a for each loop like this one (keeping it as last resolve):

```
//list1 of query result unique column2 values
//list2 of query result unique column3 values
for each (list1)
for each (list2)
HashSet<Object,Object> result = Session.createQuery("... where
t1.Column1 LIKE '%"+":list1"+"%'
and t1.Column1 LIKE '%"+":list2"+"%'").setParameter("list1",list1).setParameter("list2",list2).tolist();
HashSet<Object,Object> lastresult= new HashSet();
lastresult.add(result);
```

Comment: This might help you https://stackoverflow.com/a/13562385/10553411

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update (Solution) :

Update : As suspected, the query was treating the object's properties as raw values instead of actual objects to iterate from, so the approach I took by adding "+" sign was the mistake, I should've gone with the function 'CONCAT' instead and it did resolve my issue.

```
session.createQuery("... WHERE lower(t1.Column1) LIKE
Concat(Concat('%',lower(t2.Column2)),'%') and lower(t1.Column1) LIKE Concat(Concat('%',lower(t2.Column3)),'%')").tolist();
```

Answer (score 0):

Wrap it with single inverted commas.

'%t2.Column2%'

Comment: wouldn't consider t2.Column2 as a string and not treat it as a column , I've tried it before returns no results while there should be .

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Criteria` class to achieve same thing,

e.g

```
Criteria query = session.createCriteria(POJO class here);
query.add(Restrictions.like("t1.Column1", "t2.Column3", MatchMode.ANYWHERE));
```

Below are list of available MatchMode options:

`MatchMode.ANYWHERE` - Match the pattern anywhere in the string. 
`MatchMode.END` - Match the end of the string to the pattern.
`MatchMode.EXACT` - Match the entire string to the pattern.
`MatchMode.START` - Match the start of the string to the pattern.

Comment: Thank you very much for your input, but I'm trying my best not to use Criteria bcs it will take me time to learn it's syntax, is there no way to simply put it with pure HQL ?